# Configure C whitespace and Python whitspace independently in Emacs

Tags: emacs, whitespace, highlight

I would like to configure my Emacs whitespace options independently for C and python files, because the indent highlighting (space before tabs, etc.) does not apply to the Python coding style. I currently set the whitespace variables globally, but would like a separate (minimal) configuration for Python. Here is the relevant part of my .emacs:

```
(require 'whitespace)
(setq whitespace-line-column 80)
(setq whitespace-style '(face lines-tail indentation trailing space-before-tab))
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'whitespace-mode)
```

This works for C. Preferably I would have '(face lines-tail trailing) for Python, but I don't know how to setq just for a specific mode. What is the correct way to do this? Thanks. Using Emacs 23 in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by putting the settings into the hook along with the evocation of whitespace-mode:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (progn
              (setq whitespace-line-column 79)
              (setq whitespace-style '(face lines-tail))
              (whitespace-mode))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using [File Local Variables](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) could help you?